# How do I open a popup message from C# in my javascriptAPP?

Tags: javascript, c#, cordova, debugging, popup

At the moment I am working on an APP. I am trying to find out why the methods from my webservices are not working but because I'm working with javascript in the app developer I am not able to debug my C# (Cordova and visual studio). Is there a way for me to write popups in the C# code so I can still see the values of my objects and properies?

So:
I want to be able to force a popup from C# while running the javascript APP because I can not debug my C# code since it's only a webservice.

Answer (score 1):

**Update:**

This would be the normal way, C# is server-side and JavaScript is client-side.  Inside of the web-method your C# should generate something like:

```
JavaScript serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var response = serializer.Serialize(jsonObject);
Response.Write(response);
Response.End();
```

That would basically allow you to receive an object or collection back into the Ajax `success` or `error` for instance.

---

Since your utilizing a JavaScript Application, I'm under the notion that you're calling the service via Ajax.  Your Ajax request will contain a `success` and `error`.  These will allow you to return data from your Ajax.

```
// Sample:
$.ajax({
     url: '...',
     type: '...',
     data: { Model : jsonObject },
     success: function (response) {
         // Response would be your C# Success.
     },

     error: function (response) {
          // Response would be your C# Error.
     }
});
```

The web-service should be serializing the response back for your web-service.

Our assistance will be minimal without seeing how you call the web-service, how the web-service responds, hopefully this helps you though.

Comment: This is what I'm currently using, but I was hoping there is a way where I can avoid having to change my methods, or creating new ones, just to be able to message my object values :( And I am not sure if I'm allowed to post any of the code here, but it works like you posted. The method where I want to message my objects from is not a callable webservice method, but is being used in one of the other webmethods. I'm also completely new to all of this so to me it feels like a huge workaround to see a log/information? Or is this the normal way of things between C# and JS? Thanks for the reply!

Comment: Updated answer to reflect your comment.